Getting started with FAQ customisations
I would really like to get started on the customisation process of the FAQ in a democratic and efficient way.
Thus, under the heading for "What kind of questions can I ask here?"
I propose that we add:

Cognitive Sciences - Stack Exchange is for researchers, academics, students, and
  anyone else interested in the cognitive sciences.
  If you have a questions about

cognitive science 
psychology (e.g., cognitive, social, developmental, biological, applied, clinical, organizational, etc.)
psychiatry
neuroscience and neurobiology

then you're in the right place to ask your question.

We could then have separate meta posts that discuss additions and modifications.
In particular, I don't see the above as the final word. Rather, it would simply be better than what we have at the moment.
There are plenty of other things that I'd like to include in the FAQ (e.g., regarding standards of prior research, expectations regarding referencing, when to post here versus another stack exchange, etc). However, I'd rather save them for separate thread and get agreement on an initial opening.
Perhaps as a way of moving forward:

If you're happy for me to add the above to the FAQ, then perhaps add a comment below.
If you object post a comment. 
If you object and have an alternative, post an answer.


Sounds like a great start to me!

Looks better to me. Might want to add a bit about "expert answers" a la DBA's FAQ

@BenBrocka okay. I gave it a little tweak to incorporate the phrase "expert answers"; see below. Thanks.

Okay. I've changed the previous FAQ content:

Cognitive Sciences - Stack Exchange is for practitioners and research professionals of the cognitive sciences.

to the following

Cognitive Sciences - Stack Exchange is for researchers, academics, students, and  anyone else needing expert answers to advanced questions in the cognitive sciences.
  If you have questions about ...

Cognitive science 
Psychology (e.g., cognitive, social, developmental, biological, applied,
  clinical, organizational, etc.)
Psychiatry
Neuroscience and neurobiology

... then you're in the right place to ask your question.

This is a slight modification on the above post in line with Ben Brocka's suggestion.
As mentioned above, I just wanted to get the ball rolling on this.
Hopefully, we can now have a series of meta posts proposing and discussing specific additions and modifications to the FAQ.

I went ahead and fixed 'advaned' questions for you. ;p Also improved the formatting somewhat. Thanks for changing the FAQ! I like it.

@StevenJeuris Thanks for that. Hopefully, we grow our  FAQ a little more and incorporate some of the conclusions drawn from meta over the coming weeks and months.

Looks good. I'm not so sure about conclusions drawn from meta...do we actually have any that are significant enough and conclusive enough to add to the FAQ yet?

@BenBrocka I'm not sure about consensus, but I had in mind a few issues like: recommendations to use references and expectations towards prior research.
